# Confusion in adding method in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a new method to jQuery so that I can do something like     `$('#id').MyOwnFunc()`. My confusion is from various sites and stack overflow I can see I can use either of these methods:

```
// #1
jQuery.fn.MyOwnFunc = function() {
    var o = $(this[0]) // It's your element
    return this; // This is needed so others can keep chaining off of this
};

// #2
jQuery.fn.extend({
    MyOwnFunc: function() {
        return this.each(function() { 
            this.checked = true; 
        });
    },
});
```

So we can create a new method on jQuery by both the above ways by directly creating a method on `fn` and also using `fn.extend` so my confusions are:

1. Is my understanding wrong?
2. If no and both can be used then why do we have `fn.extend()` when we already have the option 1?
3. Which is better option?

Please kindly explain as I have already gone through many site but didn't understand why you have two ways?

Answer (score 0):

> Is my understanding wrong?

No

> If no and both can be used then why do we have fn.extend() when we already have the option 1?

It's because `extend()` is a [jQuery method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) which lets you merge the properties of *any* number of objects. In this case you're extending the existing `$.fn` object, which holds all methods which can be applied to selectors, with your new code. The `extend()` method is not specific to plugin authoring.

> Which is better option?

Either is fine. My preference is for your first method, ie. without using `extend()`, as it's more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript there is often more than one way to do the same thing.

In this case though, the two things are not the same.

`jQuery.fn` is used to add jQuery plugins, so that you can later do `$('#something').myCoolPlugin();`

`jQuery.fn.extend` allows you to add multiple plugins *at the same time*, without having to do multiple `jQuery.fn` calls, e.g:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    coolPlugin1: function() {
      // cool stuff
    },
    coolPlugin2: function() {
      // other cool stuff
    }
});
```

Is better than:

```
jQuery.fn.coolPlugin1 = function() {
  // cool stuff
};

jQuery.fn.coolPlugin2 = function() {
  // other cool stuff
};
```